# MongoDB php update returns error for existing document

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I'm trying to update a document (1 field exactly), but I'm getting unexpected error (shell update works fine). No field is updated.

OPERATION:

```
$_POST['title_en'] = 'skyfall';
$editMovie = array('$set'=>array('title_en'=>$_POST['title_en']));
//JSON: {"$set":{"title_en":"Skyfall"}} 
$update = $collection->update(array('_id'=>$_POST['_id']), $editMovie);
```

RETURNS:

```
array(5) { ["updatedExisting"]=> bool(false) ["n"]=> int(0) ["connectionId"]=> int(9) ["err"]=> NULL ["ok"]=> float(1) }
```

SHELL COMMAND WORKS LIKE A CHARM:

```
db.movies.update({"title_en":"skyfall"}, {$set:{"title_en":"Skyfall"}})
```

Comment: But the shell command is different from the PHP one. You're using `_id` in PHP, but `title_en` in the shell. Also, are you sure that `$_POST['_id']` is set to an actual ID?

Comment: I process find() to return _id's, title_en and other fields. Then I use hidden form field to hold this _id. I've checked all values with var_dump and it seems ok.

Comment: And have you tried `$update = $collection->update(array('title_en'=>$_POST['title_en']), $editMovie);`?

Comment: Well I've managed to do such update with:

    $update = $collection->update(array("_id"=>new MongoId($_POST['_id'])), $editMovie);

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with _id in MongoDB with PHP, make sure you wrap form responses with the MongoId() object to convert the string back into MongoID:

```
$update = $collection->update(array('_id' => new MongoId($_POST['_id'])), $editMovie);
```

In other words, when you're getting the id from a form response, you've essentially "cast" the MongoID back into a string, so you need to 'uncast' it back into MongoID again.

In your example where you're updating based on the existing title, your matching against a string type, so no cast is necessary.